# Brother DCP-J315W is active in terminal but not detected in Elementary OS

Tags: wifi, scanner

For a couple of days I've been trying to get my "all-in-one" Brother [DCP-J315W](http://welcome.brother.com/th-en/products-services/multi-function-centres/dcp-j315w.html) to work. I managed to make the printer work over Wi-Fi, but the scanner is not detected in GUI even though it is visible in the terminal using `brscan-skey -l`

```
SCANNER : brother3:net1;dev0 : 192.168.2.101 Active
DCP-J315W_scan : brother3:net1;dev1 : 192.168.2.101 Active
DCP-J315W_skaner : brother3:net1;dev2 : 192.168.1.101 Not responded
```

The drivers seem to be installed properly:

```
vielebny@MK-Samsung:~$ brsaneconfig3 -q | grep SCANNER
0 SCANNER "DCP-J315W" I:192.168.2.101

vielebny@MK-Samsung:~$ dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii brscan-skey:i386 0.2.4-1 Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool 
ii brscan3:i386 0.2.11-4 Brother Scanner Driver 
ii dcpj315wcupswrapper:i386 1.1.3-1 Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions 
ii dcpj315wlpr:i386 1.1.3-1 Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions 
ii printer-driver-ptouch 1.3-3ubuntu0.1 printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You don't have to add "solved" to the title as in forums, simply mark your answer as the accepted one when the system allows you to. Usually 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

After posted comment I went back to notes on this website [Polish website](http://www.magu.pl/content/view/57/29/)

I started to write in terminal:

```
$ sudo brsaneconfig3 -a name=DCPJ315W model=DCP-J315W ip=192.168.2.101
$ brsaneconfig3 -q
```

-> i got the list of all brother devices and the last was network device

```
Devices on network
0 DCPJ315W            "DCP-J315W"         I:192.168.2.101
```

So next i pinged it:

```
$ brsaneconfig3 -p

test DCPJ315W
ping 192.168.2.101 -w 10

PING 192.168.2.101 (192.168.2.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=9.70 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=4.22 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=3 ttl=255 time=3.32 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=4 ttl=255 time=4.86 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=5 ttl=255 time=3.55 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=6 ttl=255 time=4.92 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=7 ttl=255 time=7.93 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=8 ttl=255 time=3.80 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=9 ttl=255 time=3.76 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.101: icmp_req=10 ttl=255 time=3.63 ms

--- 192.168.2.101 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9014ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.322/4.974/9.706/2.027 ms`
```

Soi started Xsane and after that... voila... it started to work! Remotely!

To be precise my sytem is:
Elementary OS Luna 0.2 64 bit and scanner drivers are also 64bit. The printer drivers are 32bit

Comment: sim - I am really beginner with linux. For me most important is I got it working remotely. I think the key to that was using the first command with sudo which is not that obvious for beginners like me. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: You did very well in debugging this and writing it up for a first timer, keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks but for me this does not seem to be working, under juno with my MFC-5460CN.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MFC8480DN and have only ever been able to send scans to the computer running `brscan-skey` *from* the scanner/printer, never remote control the scanner/printer.  How are you trying to send scans? The command you're showing `brscan-skey -l` just shows that the receiving software can see the scanner.

If you look at the usage for `brscan-skey` it states the following:

```
$ brscan-skey --help
This tool enables you to scan a document by using the
Scan key on the Brother MFC through the network.
```

If you're attempting to use the SANE/XSANE interface I believe you'll need additional drivers installed, I've successfully used the scanner in my Brother MFC8480DN to send jobs to GIMP in this manner.

I believe everything you need is available here on the Brother website: [Scan-key-tool install](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn3.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have done everything according to Brother website. With no luck though. Weird thing is when I type brscan-skey --help i get different message: vielebny@MK-Samsung:~$ brscan-skey --help
   Copyright 2007-2012 Brother Industries, Ltd

Comment: I have an older version of the s/w, I saw no point in installing newer version, gives me nothing above what I already get from this version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the line brother4 to the end of 
/etc/sane.d/dll.conf (MFC-J625)

For you it should be brother3